# Can azure table storage be accessed from Web applications hosted on IIS

Tags: azure-storage

I have a web application that is hosted on IIS. I do not want to create it as a Web role. Can I still access azure table storage from web application that is hosted on IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Just grab the Windows Azure Storage package on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and then do something like this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

// Create the table client
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the table if it doesn't exist
string tableName = "people";
tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(tableName);
```

Then do what ever you need to do.  You can replace the *"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"* with a proper connection string like "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...".  You will need to use upload a certificate to use a https connection.

**Just know that you will be billed for all the data going out of the Azure data center**.  I would not recommend using Azure Storage as the primary data storage solution for you website if you have a lot of traffic.  It would definitely better to host your application in a web role or an Azure Web Site.